# Apple Watch Unpaired ActivateSession slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch

In the AppDelegate in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I connect the
watch to the App.

```
if ([WCSession isSupported]) {
   WCSession *session = [WCSession defaultSession];
   session.delegate = self;
   [session activateSession];
}
```

This is working fine for most cases. However when users did have a watch
paired and they unpair the watch, we are experiencing delays in the
[session activateSession]. It will take approxiately 7-8 seconds for this
call to be executed. This is causing a huge delay in the App startup.

I suspect that this is a Apple bug, I do not expecct Apple to make a fix for this on short notice.

As I workaround I'm looking I want to check if a watch is paired, before the activateSession. However 'session' does not contain valid data. How can I check if a watch is paired, before the 'session activateSession'
statement?

This occurs both in iOS9.3 and iOS10.0.1, I have not tested other versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That certainly does sound like a bug. As a workaround you could either:

- do the activation on a background thread, or
- take advantage of the asynchronous activation added for WCSession in iOS 9.3 and watchOS 2.2 by implementing the [`session:activationDidCompleteWithActivationState:error:`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity/wcsessiondelegate/1615679-session)

Comment: It is strongly advised to perform the activation in the AppDelegate, so the first workaround is not possible.

Comment: The 2nd workaround works perfectly. Just include the method session:activationDidCompleteWithActivationState:error: (no content needed). Thanks!